# Is there a way to avoid whenever ricompile all?

Tags: magento2

I need ricompile if change a bit one controller or block or view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends whether your magento store is in developer or default mode (check in `php bin/magento deploy:mode:show`) then classses in var/generation are created on the fly is missing. So on your local machine or some testing server you can simply remove the class you need to "recompile". If magento2 is in production mode then no, all classes and static content must be deployed. Missing anything means 404 (for static content) or fatal error (for missing class in var/generation).